# InnoDB: breaking and fixing indexes

Tags: mysql, innodb, percona

From time to time it happens that some indexes in our tables get broken and the DB start consuming 100% CPU load and in some time it gets completely stuck. Even simple queries won't finish and restarts don't help.

What I found is to either drop and recreate indexes one by one (which might take a loooong time and lot of investigation) or just calling `alter table mytable engine=innodb;` on suspicious table. This works actually quite well, it fixes everything and everything gets back to normal. But I have no idea what actually happens in background and why it helps. Also – would it help to do this manually once a month? Is it a good idea to automatize this? Is there some way to do some DB health check?

Comment: Are you running the most up-to-date version of MySQL? Have you tried a full dump, scratch-built restore of your DB? Can you reproduce the problem on any other machine? You may be dealing with buggy software or a defective piece of hardware, like a glitchy bank of memory.

Comment: Yes this happens roughly once year and last time it was on a different machine. I am running up-to-date Percona on Debian.

Comment: It's worth experimenting with MariaDB and MySQL to see if it's an issue and/or contact Percona support.

Comment: What version?  `FULLTEXT` or regular `INDEX`?

Comment: How big is the table?  Is it essentially one query?  Did you try simply `ANALYZE TABLE`?  Let's see the query and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

A guess...

You have an older version of MySQL/Percona, one that either does not have "persistent statistics" or does not have it enabled.

And you have a nasty query that sometimes leads the Optimizer to pick the wrong query plan.

The quick fix (that may or may not work) is to run `ANALYZE TABLE` of the table(s) in the slow query.

A better fix may be to upgrade the version.

Meanwhile, let's see the query, its `EXPLAIN`, and `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table involved.  The may be a way to reformulate it to be less flaky.

Comment: Well, we have Percona version 5.7.16-10, which shouldn't be too old. Also this happened to us before some time ago on completely different table/query. From `analyze table` I never got anything else than `OK`. I would rather like to know what happens when `alter table mytable engine=innodb;` is executed. This always helped and I have no idea why.

Comment: Alter..engine is the same as `OPTIMIZE`.  Analyze quickly does a few probes to recalculate the "statistics", then says "OK".  I _suspect_ that the statistics had gotten out of whack for the query.

Comment: Okay, would it be safe to run `OPTIMIZE` automatically once a month on all tables?

Comment: It locks the table for a time roughly proportional to the size.  It is otherwise "safe".  I don't recommend it -- except I can't think of another solution for your situation.  You are saying that `ANALYZE` did not lead to a change in the query plan?